# TypeScript error in Single function for both Slider onChange and Input onChange in Material-UI component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, slider

`handleChange` using to update `usesrState` for MUI `<Slider />` and `<Input />` The solution

```
  const handleChange = (event: Event, newValue: number | number[]) => {
    const inputValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement)
      .value as unknown as number;
    setValue(inputValue || (newValue as number));
  };
```

working good. At the same time the TypeScript getting error when using parameters differently  from Slider and Input fields.

```
Type '(event: Event, newValue: number | number[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>'.
  Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.ts(2322)
```

Looking for better solution in TypeScript.

[image: Edit hopeful-dhawan-j7fpc4]

Answer (score 0):

You're basically using the `handleChange` function to handle two different types of events with a single function signature. The `onChange` event for the `<Input />` component expects a `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`, while the `onChange` event for the `<Slider />` component expects a different function signature that includes the `newValue`.

To resolve this, you can split the `handleChange` function [into two separate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), each dedicated to the specific component it handles. You can modify your `InputSlider` component to use two separate handlers:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, Grid, Slider, Input } from "@mui/material";

export default function InputSlider() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(10);

  // Handler for the Slider component
  const handleSliderChange = (
    event: Event,
    newValue: number | number[],
  ) => {
    setValue(Array.isArray(newValue) ? newValue[0] : newValue);
  };

  // Handler for the Input component
  const handleInputChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
  ) => {
    setValue(Number(event.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 250 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
        <Grid item xs>
          <Slider
            value={value}
            onChange={handleSliderChange}
            aria-labelledby="input-slider"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Input
            type="number"
            size="small"
            value={value}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            inputProps={{
              min: 10,
              max: 100,
            }}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

This way, `handleSliderChange` is used for the `<Slider />` component's `onChange` event, and `handleInputChange` is used for the `<Input />` component's `onChange` event. Each handler is now correctly typed for the component it's associated with, which should eliminate the TypeScript error you were encountering.

Try [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/4szj5f?embed=1&file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9m62l20006356azn26ou8g%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9m62l20002356aybpj8yr6%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9m62l20003356akke761so%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9m62l20005356a2vw3fayo%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr9m62l20002356aybpj8yr6%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9m62l20002356aybpj8yr6%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr9mexs8009w356a036vjjhb%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9m62l10001356ax0vae3ui%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpackage.json%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9m7af00002356afrf241f1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A7%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A11%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A7%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A11%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FDemo.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9mexs8009w356a036vjjhb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clr9m62l20005356a2vw3fayo%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9m62l20005356a2vw3fayo%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr9meodo008a356apgivtacq%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9meodo008a356apgivtacq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clr9m62l20003356akke761so%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9m62l20003356akke761so%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr9mehou006o356a4ihdzfxe%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9mehou006o356a4ihdzfxe%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

**EDIT**:

If you have to use `handleChange` for both, then try this:

```js
const handleChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<{}> | Event, // Use a more general type for the event
    newValue?: number | number[],
  ) => {
    // Check if the event is from the Slider component
    if (newValue !== undefined) {
      setValue(Array.isArray(newValue) ? newValue[0] : newValue);
    } else {
      // Handle the Input component event
      const inputEvent = event as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
      setValue(Number(inputEvent.target.value));
    }
  };
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Looking for solution in single function `handleChange`, will that work with TYpeScript ?

Comment: still getting type error `Type '(event: React.ChangeEvent<{}> | Event, newValue: number | number[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>'.
  Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1`